# FFMPEG Overlay video's sound not starting from beginning

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to overlay video over video on specific time and i can get it successfully.
But problem is that audio always start from the begining.
Actual output :  Audio also start from specific time when overlay video visible.

I am using the following command to get overlay video ouput:

```
'-i ' + filePath1 + '  -i ' + filePath2 + ' \
                            -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=180:180:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,[1:v] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h):enable='+ "'between(t," + startTime + "," + endTime + ")'" + '" \
                            -map 0:a -c:a  copy  ' + fileout + ''
```

Comment: Show the actual command being executed and show the full log from your command. Otherwise I have to make to many assumptions to provide an answer.

Comment: This is already whole command which i used in react native. you can make assumption so it might help me.

Comment: At least show the log from ffmpeg.